# Lua: how do I add display objects required from external functions to display groups?

Tags: lua, coronasdk, displayobject, corona-storyboard

In a storyboard scene, I require a bunch of display objects from external functions. When I attempt to add these to the scene's display group, I get the error "table expected."

```
function scene:createScene(event)
    local group=self.view
    local shieldDisplay = shieldDisplay.new()
    group:insert(shieldDisplay)
end
```

The external function looks like this:

```
function shieldDisplay.new()
    shieldDisp = display.newText("Shield: "..tostring(Cshield), 1165, 20, native.systemFont, 30)
    shieldDisp:setTextColor(9,205,235)
end
return shieldDisplay
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return object must be inside on the function that you're calling.

```
function shieldDisplay.new()
    local shieldDisp = display.newText("Shield: "..tostring(Cshield), 1165, 20, native.systemFont, 30)
    shieldDisp:setTextColor(9,205,235)
    return shieldDisp 
end
```

Comment: This kind of works when I add both return shieldDisp inside the function and return shieldDisplay at the end of the scene. However, the shieldDisplay object is now invisible when I add it to the self.view group.

Answer (score 0):

```
function scene:createScene(event)
    local group=self.view
    local shieldDisplay = shieldDisplay.new()
    group:insert(shieldDisplay)
end
```

Try changing it to

```
function scene:createScene(event)
    local group=self.view
    local shieldDisplay = shieldDisplay.new
    group:insert(shieldDisplay)
end
```

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't change anything.